# Compiling the whole asp.net website on Mono at once

Tags: asp.net, mono, compilation

i am compiling the asp.net web application page by page using "gmcs" command in Mono.
But i want to compile the whole asp.net website at once using Mono command.

For ex:
gmcs /t:library /out:bin/AJAX.dll -r:System.dll -r:System.Web.dll -r:bin/AjaxControlToolkit.dll  Default.aspx.cs Default.aspx.designer.cs

I do not want to do like the above one, instead i want to compile the whole folder containing files at once.

Plz let me know.thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Monodevelop?

Comment: i'm using mono 2.6.7 on linux rhel

Comment: So you're not using an IDE then? Have you considered using MonoDevelop (http://monodevelop.com)? That way you have an easy method for compiling a whole ASP.NET project at once.

Comment: i'm using linux rhel 4, does monodevelop work on it. And if i install monodevelop on windows and compile the project in it and copy the compiled files to mono 2.6.7 on linux.. will it work.

Comment: Yes, MonoDevelop is a cross-platform IDE that will also work on Linux. Have a look on the website.
And yes, you can also compile the code on a Windows machine and copy the files over to your Linux box, as Mono is a cross-platform implementation of the .NET framework.

Comment: a million thanks to you if this works out or else i'll reply you back for more clarification....

Answer (score 2):

I used to run `xbuild` on projects created using Visual Studio as IDE. Worked perfectly! I'm not sure if MonoDevelop generates a `.csproj` file for your web application but that's the best way to compile ASP.NET, which, however, was supposed to be compiled automatically by `xsp` on the first request

Comment: Did you mean to say flush the /tmp folder recursively? Thank you.